# How do I repeat div classes using JavaScript only?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Okay, I'm unsure how to word the question, but basically I want to repeat my div containers that have a class of "blocks" using only javascript, no HTML (other than the HTML needed to start a page).  IF I were doing this using HTML the result should look exactly like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/nqZjB/1/

```
   <div class = "blocks"> <!-- Repeats three times -->
```

However as I stated in the description I do not want to use any HTML, so here is my fiddle with javascript only.

How do I make div class blocks repeat three times as in my HTML example using only javascript?  Of course in real life I would use HTML for this as javascript is unnecessary, but I want to do this in pure javascript so I can learn.  Also as a sidenote if you have a better way as to how I should have worded the question, let me know.
Thanks (:

http://jsfiddle.net/TbCYH/1/

Comment: Have you tried using a loop?

Comment: I am a noob at javascript hence this is why I am learning.  As in loop you mean another for loop right?  By the way was the -1 for poorly worded question because I didn't know how to word the question.

Answer (score 7):

It's good you see the use of making a function of a re-occurring pattern.

Before posting it in StackOverflow, have you tried doing it yourself?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kychan/W7Jxu/

```
//    we will use a container to place our blocks.
//     fetch the element by id and store it in a variable.
var container = document.getElementById('container');

function block(mClass, html) {
    //extra html you want to store.
    return '<div class="' + mClass + '">' + html + '</div>';
}

//    code that loops and makes the blocks.
//    first part: creates var i
//    second:     condition, if 'i' is still smaller than three, then loop.
//    third part: increment i by 1;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // append the result of function 'block()' to the innerHTML
    // of the container.
    container.innerHTML += block('block', 'data');
}
```

---

**Edit**: JS has changed a lot since the original post. If you do not require compatibility, use `const`, `template literals`, `class` and `querySelector` to make the code a bit cleaner. The following code has a `Builder` class and assumes there is a div with ID 'container':

```
// create class builder.
class Builder {
  //    create constructor, accept an element selector, i.e #container.
  constructor(targetContainerSelector) {
    //  search element by given selector and store it as a property.
    this.targetContainer = document.querySelector(targetContainerSelector);
  }

    //  method to append to innerHtml of target container.
  appendUsingInnerHtml(divAsHtml) {
    this.targetContainer.innerHTML += divAsHtml;
  }

  //    method to append to target container using DOM elements.
  appendUsingDom(divAsDom) {
    this.targetContainer.appendChild(divAsDom);
  }
}

//  constant to hold element selector.
const myTargetContainer = '#container';
//  constant to set the class if required.
const myDivClass = 'my-class';

//  constant to hold the instantiated Builder object.
const builder = new Builder(myTargetContainer);

//  loop 3 times.
for (let i=0; i<3; i++) {
  // call method to append to target container using innerHtml.
    builder.appendUsingInnerHtml(`<div class="${myDivClass}}">innerhtml div text</div>`);


  // OR.. build using DOM objects.

  //    create the div element.
  const div = document.createElement('div');

  //    create text element, add some text to it and append it to created div.
  div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('dom div text'));

  //    call method to append div DOM object to target container.
  builder.appendUsingDom(div);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, your example is a bit better because you use parameters and the function is more reusable.  Thanks for the descriptions with your code, makes things easier on me for learning purposes.

Comment: Your welcome, we all start somewhere. I wanted to give you the extra help i never had!

Answer (score 2):

Please note: Every time something is added to the DOM, it forces the browser to reflow the DOM (computation of element's position and geometry).

Adding everything at once, improve speed, efficiency and performance of a code.

(ref: [document.createDocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment))

```
window.onload = Create();

function Create() {
          
   // create the container
   var mainContainer = document.createElement('div');
   mainContainer.id = 'mainContainer';
   // add all style in one go
   mainContainer.setAttribute('style', 'witdht: 400px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid green; margin-left: 20px;');

   
   var divBlocks1 = document.createElement('div');
   divBlocks1.className = 'blocks';
   divBlocks1.setAttribute('style', 'width: 100px; heigth: 100px; border: 1px solid black; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px; floar: left;');

   var divBlocks2 = divBlocks1.cloneNode(false); // copy/clone above div
   var divBlocks3 = divBlocks1.cloneNode(false); // copy/clone above div
   
   // everything is still in memory
   mainContainer.appendChild(divBlocks1);
   mainContainer.appendChild(divBlocks2);
   mainContainer.appendChild(divBlocks3);
   
   // now we append everything to the document
   document.body.appendChild(mainContainer);

}
```

Good luck
:)

Comment: Yet another good answer.  I always felt a loop was a must, but you did it in a way where you didn't need a loop and where everything can be applied at once.  Being that I'm still a newbie at JavaScript I will remember this way as well as the other answers on this thread to further my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating the elements before hand and then appending them to the main container, consider dynamically creating and appending them in a loop.

http://jsfiddle.net/TbCYH/6/

```
   for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       var divBlock = document.createElement("div");                
       divBlock.className = "blocks";
       mainContainer.appendChild(divBlock);       
   }
```

In the above code snippet a div is being created and appended for each iteration of the loop (which is set to cease at 3).

Also if possible, always use CSS classes rather than modifying the styles for each div directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var d=0;d<10;d++){
   var aDiv = document.createElement('div');
       aDiv.className = "block";
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(aDiv);
}
```