# Can we repeat vertically and dynamically watermark text as background?

Tags: html, css

I am creating an HTML report (regular HTML) that contains information on a sale.  I have the requirement of 'water marking' reports with 'Pending' status.

I have watermarked the reports with the code below.  The only problem is that when the user loads the report in a browser and then clicks Print, only the first page is watermarked.  Each page needs to be watermarked, therefore I need to repeat the watermarking vertically only.

CSS

```
#background{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:0;
    background:white;
    display:block;
    min-height:50%; 
    min-width:50%;
    color:yellow;
}

#content{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}

#bg-text{
    color:lightgrey;
    font-size:120px;
    transform:rotate(300deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(300deg);
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="background">
        <p id="bg-text">Pending Sale</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Unfortunately the system does not support use of external images for the background.  I have reports that fit in 1 page, and other reports that are 10+ pages long.  Therefore the watermarking needs to be dynamic.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: if external images are not supported, [base64 inline image](http://www.base64-image.de/) could be an alternative

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use outside resources like svg, background images, ex.... here is a duct-tape solution. This uses Javascript, and no Jquery since it would require loading an outside resource.

Basically the script takes the height of the #content div (which has all your content) and assigns it to #background. The background div is set so it doesn't overflow past the content.

```
<style> 
#background{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    background:white;
        width: 600px;
    color :yellow;
    overflow: hidden;

}

#content{
    position:absolute; 
    width: 600px;
}

.bg-text{

    color:lightgrey;
    font-size:120px;
    transform:rotate(300deg);   
    -webkit-transform:rotate(300deg);
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    padding-left: 100px;


}</style>
```

Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
function oncode(){

    var clientHeight = document.getElementById('content').clientHeight;
     document.getElementById("background").style.height = clientHeight + 'px';
}

</script>
```

Load the script: (put this at the end of the document)

```
<script>
//call after page loaded
window.onload=oncode ; 
</script>
```

Your document:

```
 <div id="background">
        <p class="bg-text">Pending Sale</p> <p class="bg-text">Pending Sale</p> <p class="bg-text">Pending Sale</p> <p class="bg-text">Pending Sale</p> <p class="bg-text">Pending Sale</p> <p class="bg-text">Pending Sale</p> <p class="bg-text">Pending Sale</p> <p class="bg-text">Pending Sale</p> <p class="bg-text">Pending Sale</p> <p class="bg-text">Pending Sale</p> <p class="bg-text">Pending Sale</p> <p class="bg-text">Pending Sale</p> <p class="bg-text">Pending Sale</p> <p class="bg-text">Pending Sale</p> <p class="bg-text">Pending Sale</p> <p class="bg-text">Pending Sale</p> <p class="bg-text">Pending Sale</p> <p class="bg-text">Pending Sale</p> <p class="bg-text">Pending Sale</p> <p class="bg-text">Pending Sale</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
   Listing stuff
```

Repeat the pending sale div a whole bunch of times...

Refer to this stackover flow to see how to repeat the backround div a certian amount in JS so it's not cheezy like my example: [How do I repeat div classes using JavaScript only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183068/how-do-i-repeat-div-classes-using-javascript-only)

Make sure to limit the amount of times your background div gets repeated in javascript so it doesn't cause issues.

Set the content width and the background width to 600px to limit the amount of resizing when printing the page.